# XML Join Step in Pentaho Kettle is very low in Performance

Tags: xml, pentaho, kettle

My requirement is somewhat tricky. A complex XML needs to be generated from text file input. I have successfully done that but it involves '11 XML joins'. Because of that performance of code is pathetic when data-set is of high volume.

How can I code for complex XML generation with good performance ?

Any suggestions!!

After some suggestions,I removed all joins and taken resort of stream lookup(as showed in kettle Sample) and 'modified java script' for final join.

But it's failing at 'final join step'. Below is the join where it's failing and throwing 'out of memory error'

```
var request = new XML()

request = <newbiz xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.crsoftwareinc.com/xml/ns/titanium/common/v1_0 newbiz.xsd" xmlns="http://www.crsoftwareinc.com/xml/ns/titanium/common/v1_0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <newbiz-header>
        <total-consumers>1</total-consumers>
        <creditor-name>DefCrdtr</creditor-name>
        <total-principal>1</total-principal>
        <total-charge>1</total-charge>
        <total-interest>1</total-interest>
        <total-balance>1</total-balance>
    </newbiz-header>
    <consumers>{xmlConsumerNewFinal}</consumers>
</newbiz>

var xmlconsumers_final=request.toXMLString();
```

Any suggestions!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, using the xml join step its really slow performance, i removed all this steps and replaced by **script step**, is e4x ecmascript (which is included in pentaho kettle, is rhino javascript engine and specially conceived to work with xml)

for instance, you can use the `var foo = new XML();` 
not included in other js engines

everything will be faster and simple building your xmls using this technique.
take a peek to the doc:
http://wso2.com/project/mashup/0.2/docs/e4xquickstart.html

Comment: I accepted your answer as it helped in performance. but as it exceeds 400K rows it fails, throwing 'out of memory error'. I have updated my question with script that I scribbled as per your suggestion. Anything I can further do to improve performance?

Comment: Thanks but I have already raised that to 8GB. I want to find an optimal way to do this. When I use cartesian join,instead of script, it's working. I am baffled as I want to use the script.

Comment: treat the final step as strings concatenations, not using xml object. this shoul be much better ram performance